# Setting up Instant Payment Notification with PHP - PayPal

Tags: php, api, paypal, token, identity

I have set up a PayPal Sandbox account and have created a script to take payments using PHP/cURL which basically follows [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-process-credit-cards-with-paypal-payments-pro-using-php/). We have already purchased a PayPal Payments Pro account to use it with. Now I need to set up [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/acc/ipn-info-outside) In order to show payment details on our confirmation page and keep track of transactions in our own database.

Questions:
How do I set up IPN in the PayPal Sandbox?
How does IPN tie into the NVP API I Used? I've seen several [PHP Tutorials with code samples](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2011/09/28/using-php-with-paypals-ipn-instant-paypal-notification-to-automate-your-digital-delivery/) but none of them explain how to set it up with the API.

References:
Here is the [NVP API Manual](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_nvpapi_developerguide.pdf).
Here  is the [Order Management Integration Manual](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/en_US/files/developer/PP_OrderMgmt_IntegrationGuide.pdf).
Here's an [FAQ type post](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/acc/ipn-info-outside) on PayPal.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IPNs should be enabled for you be default. If not, you can enable them from your PayPal account -> Profile -> My Selling Tools -> Instant payment notifications.

IPNs are triggered by API calls such as DoExpressCheckoutPayment, DoDirectPayment, RefundTransaction etc. In general, PayPal generates an IPN message when external events arise that might affect a transaction, such as disputes, chargebacks, eCheck clearing, and various recurring payment and subscription events.

When you setup your IPN listener,

1. Ensure it is reachable from the internet. You can use the [IPN simulator](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator) to verify reachability.
2. Register a global IPN listener URL in the IPN settings page above OR provide a IPN notification URL with every API call. See the [API reference](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/#merchant) to understand how this can be done.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful information. If you don't mind answering an offtopic question, what is the benifit of setting up recurring payments through paypal as opposed to running doDirectPayment script from my own server ever 30 days, for example?

Comment: - You do not have the hassle of setting up a cron job etc. You do not need to store buyer's credit card info if you use recurring payments. Another advantage is that you can create recurring payment plans with a PayPal account as your funding source instead of a credit card.